# How to speed up repeated string searching

Tags: string, vba

I've got a UDF that searches a cell for several substrings. The output of the formula depends on which substring is found:

```
Function StringSearch(Rge As Range) As String
Dim Str As String, Output As String
Str = Rge.Value

If InStr(Str, "words") > 0 Then Output = "Output 1"
If InStr(Str, "other words") > 0 Then Output = "Output 2"
If InStr(Str, "different words") > 0 Then Output = "Output 3"

StringSearch = Output

End Function
```

I've included a reduced form of the function here - in reality the InStr function is called about 20 times to search for different strings.

The problem is that the function is very slow. It needs to be applied to hundreds of cells. So I was hoping for some advice on how I can speed it up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to look for all possible scenarios of `Instr` for every word tested inside the range ? are you testing if the cell is inside that range ?

Comment: What about checking it like `If ... Then... ElseIf....`?

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribzew I considered a regular `If .... Then... ElseIf....` approach, but it doesn't speed up the code. The reason is that this function often none of the `InStr` statements return a positive value (none of them find the string they are looking for) so the speed improvement is marginal. @Shai Rado Yes. I need to check weather the string contains any one of "words", "other words", "different words". There are about 20 of these things that I need to check for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if it will make much difference, but you can try the `Like` operator

```
Function StringSearch(s As String) As String
    If s Like "*words*" Then StringSearch = "Output 1": Exit Function
    If s Like "*other words*" Then StringSearch = "Output 2": Exit Function
    If s Like "*different words*" Then StringSearch = "Output 3": Exit Function
End Function
```

but an Excel function would be much faster than a UDF

```
= If( CountIf( A1, "*words*"           ), "Output 1", 
  If( CountIf( A1, "*other words*"     ), "Output 2", 
  If( CountIf( A1, "*different words*" ), "Output 3", "" )
```

Comment: I didn't realize how much faster the excel function is compared to a UDF (and not sure why excel functions are faster than UDFs?). I ended up writing the behemoth function in excel and it's very fast now. Thanks

Comment: @Mas my guess is the [Multithreaded Recalculation in Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687899.aspx) and because they are optimized to be fast. I even use them in VBA to speed up some of my code.

Comment: @Slai compilation at runtime also slows UDFs down quite a bit afaik